# How to make a \big-type command for “normal” size

Tags: scaling

I know this request sounds totally ridiculous at first, but I need it for technical reasons. I would like a custom scaling command like `\big`, `\Big`, `\bigg`, `\Bigg`, but one that corresponds to “normal size”. We could call it `\normalscaling` or something like that. Importantly, it should exhibit the same behaviour as the other scaling commands, so e.g. `\normalscaling.` should yield nothing, while `\normalscaling<` should yield `\langle`. I know the general definition of hte `\big`-style commands, but I am not entirely sure how to modify it to get “no scaling”, i.e. what number to plug in instead of `\@ne`.

(But why on earth? It is because I am creating a macro system that inserts scaled parentheses, and I want “normal” scaling to behave like other scaling in the above terms. And I want it to expand and behave exactly the same way as the above commands.)

Comment: How about `\let\normalscaling\relax`?

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes This does not yield the desired behaviour for `.` and `<` etc.

Comment: Good point.  Can you elaborate on the "etc"?

Comment: I have also been wondering about `\def\normalscaling#1{\left.\middle#1\right.}`, but this does not look to me like the “right” way to do it.

Comment: Well, everything you can do with `\big` etc., I also want to be able to do with `\normalscaling`. So `\normalscaling.` should yield nothing, and `\normalscaling<` should yield `\langle`. I forgot the other things you can do with `\big`, but I think `\big|` and `\big/` also replace `|` and `/` with “real” delimiters.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `amsmath`'s way of creating `\big` commands:

[image: Sample output]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\normalscaling}{\bBigg@{0.8}}
\newcommand{\normalscalingl}{\mathopen\normalscaling}
\newcommand{\normalscalingr}{\mathclose\normalscaling}
\newcommand{\normalscalingm}{\mathrel\normalscaling}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\begin{equation*}
  \Bigl( w + \bigl( x + \normalscalingl( y + z \normalscalingr) \bigr)
  \Bigr)
\end{equation*}

\begin{equation*}
  \bigl\langle \psi \bigm| \bigr.
\end{equation*}

\begin{equation*}
  \normalscalingl\langle \psi \normalscalingm| \normalscalingr.
\end{equation*}

\end{document}
```

However, you might want to choose a shorter command name...

Why the argument `0.8` to `\bBigg@`?  This factor is multiplied on to `\big@size` which is `1.2` times the height of a mathstrut.  `1/1.2 = 0.83333...` but I just used `0.8`.

Edit: if you need to preserve the placement of subscripts etc. then you can instead use the following definition

```
\def\newnormalscaling#1{\bBigg@{0.8}#1{}}
```

`\bBigg@` produces a group that ends with a `\right.` and this results in lower than standard placement of the subscript.  Adding a following `\mathord` fixes that.  I am not 100% sure it won't have undesired side effects, but placed inside a `\mathopen`, `\mathclose` or `\mathrel` in `l`, `r` or `m` variants, it should work fine:

[image: Second sample]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\normalscaling}{\bBigg@{0.8}}
\newcommand{\normalscalingl}{\mathopen\normalscaling}
\newcommand{\normalscalingr}{\mathclose\normalscaling}
\newcommand{\normalscalingm}{\mathrel\normalscaling}
\def\newnormalscaling#1{\bBigg@{0.8}#1{}}
\newcommand{\newnormalscalingl}{\mathopen\newnormalscaling}
\newcommand{\newnormalscalingr}{\mathclose\newnormalscaling}
\newcommand{\newnormalscalingm}{\mathrel\newnormalscaling}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\begin{equation*}
  \Bigl( w + \bigl( x + \normalscalingl( y + z \normalscalingr) \bigr)
  \Bigr)
\end{equation*}

\begin{equation*}
  \bigl\langle \psi \bigm| \bigr.
\end{equation*}

\begin{equation*}
  \normalscalingl\langle \psi \normalscalingm| \normalscalingr.
\end{equation*}

\begin{equation*}
  (a)_{b}  \normalscalingl(a\normalscalingr)_{b}
  \left.\right)_{b}
\end{equation*}

\begin{equation*}
  \Bigl( w + \bigl( x + \newnormalscalingl( y + z \newnormalscalingr) \bigr)
  \Bigr)
\end{equation*}

\begin{equation*}
  \bigl\langle \psi \bigm| \bigr.
\end{equation*}

\begin{equation*}
  \newnormalscalingl\langle \psi \newnormalscalingm| \newnormalscalingr.
\end{equation*}

\begin{equation*}
  (a)_{b}  \newnormalscalingl(a\newnormalscalingr)_{b}
  \left.\right)_{b}
\end{equation*}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I'd simply use 0 instead of 0.8

Comment: Thanks, @AndrewSwann and @egreg. As I said above, I knew about the `amsmath` definitions, but was unsure about which numbers to insert instead of `\@ne`, `1.5`, etc. You and egreg cleared it up together. Thanks again!

Comment: @egreg Testing shows that the position of indices is changed when applying this method. Compare `(a)_{b}` to `\normascalingl( a \normalscaling)_{b}` to see what I mean. Can this be fixed somehow?

Answer (score 5):

Here, i just intercept the special arguments, such as `.`, `<`, `>`, and `|`, and substitute the appropriate non-scaled command.  Otherwise, I just pass through the argument.

As you can see from the last two lines, the `\normalscalingl` and `\normalscalingr` implementation works as desired, even though `\normalscaling` itself has to work through an `\ifx` chain (for example, compare last line to output of `$\normalscaling)x\normalscaling( \rightarrow y$`, where `\mathopen` and `\mathclose` are not invoked... spacing around `\rightarrow` becomes incorrect).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{newtxmath}
\newcommand\normalscaling[1]{%
  \ifx.#1\else
  \ifx<#1\langle\else
  \ifx>#1\rangle\else
  \ifx|#1\vert\else
  #1
  \fi\fi\fi\fi
}
\newcommand\normalscalingl{\mathopen\normalscaling}
\newcommand\normalscalingr{\mathclose\normalscaling}
\begin{document}
$< \langle \Big< \Big\langle \Big. \Big/ \Big|$

$< \langle \normalscaling< \normalscaling\langle \normalscaling. 
  \normalscaling/ \normalscaling|$

$\normalscalingl(x\normalscalingr) \rightarrow y$

$\normalscalingl)x\normalscalingr( \rightarrow y$
\end{document}
```

[image]